# How to correlate WSAGetLastError with Socket error code

Tags: sockets, winsock

I  see a list of Winsock error codes here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

But when I call `WSAGetLastError()` the result is -2147014848 (or 0x80072740)

How do you correlate the two ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a `HRESULT` style Microsoft error code. The low 16 bits is the error code. The high bit is set which is the severity bit. That indicates a failure, and of course it makes the value negative if interpreted as a signed 32 bit integer.

The upper 16 bits (minus for the upper 5 bits, which are flags) is a facility code.

See here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT

So this is an error, in facility 7, whose number is 0x2740, or 10048.

And that would be (thanks to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

ta daa: `{WSA}EADDRINUSE`

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's documentation for Windows Socket 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/handling-winsock-errors),

> *"[...] a specific error number can be retrieved by calling the `WSAGetLastError` function [and] a Winsock error code can be converted to an `HRESULT` for use in a remote procedure call (RPC) using `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`."*

I agree with [@Kaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250772/kaz)'s answer that the error code you received of `0x80072740` appears to be an `HRESULT`, however, something feels off here with the sole fact that you are even getting an `HRESULT`. When calling `WSAGetLastError()`, you should essentially be getting back a Win32 status code in all cases from my understanding. I don't see any posted code, so I can't be entirely certain you didn't convert the code to an HRESULT first.

However, you are safest using the following statement when retrieving back an Windows Socket API (WSA) error code:

```
/* A WSA function indicated an error above. */

Result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 (WSAGetLastError ());
```

This is analogous when using the normal function `GetLastError()`, which returns a definite Win32 status code.

By using this statement, you can guarentee that you are always dealing with an `HRESULT`. Also, even if `WSAGetLastError()` returns an `HRESULT` sometimes, calling the macro function `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32` will just return back the same `HRESULT` unmodified (see actual `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32` definition [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-hresult_from_win32)).

Lastly, when trying to figure out a specific Microsoft Windows specific error code, I recommend using the following error code look-up site: https://errorcodelookup.com/. The error code you provided refers to the error code `WSAEADDRINUSE` (`0x80072740`):

> *"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."*